# Why is this text aligned center?

Tags: html

I have tried to align the text left but it is not working. How can I fix this or do I have to revamp it?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pixelar Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pixelar Regular'), url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/38239/PIXELAR REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
}

a {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-style: outset;
  color: black;
  background-color: silver;
}

a:hover {
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #9a9999;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Pixelar Regular', sans-serif;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-style: inset;
  size: 1;
}

.outer {
  background-color: silver;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #c6c6c6;
  width: 380px;
  text-align: left;
}

.un {
  background-color: #c30000;
  border-color: #d84040;
  padding: 00px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
}

html {
  background-color: #018281;
}

.taskbar {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  position: fixed;
  border-style: inset;
  height: 4%;
}

.start {
  background-color: silver;
  border-style: outset;
  width: 35px;
}

.start:hover {
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
  border-style: inset;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;transform:translateX(-50px)">
  <center>
    <img src="https://webstockreview.net/images/windows-95-icons-png-2.png" alt="My pc" width="150" style=”display:block”>
    <p style="transform:translateY(-47px)">My pc</p>
  </center>
</div><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="outer">

  <div class="topbar" style="font-size:25px;color:white;text-shadow: 1px 0px #ffffff;text-align:left;">
    &nbsp;Windows
  </div>
  <aba style "text-align: left;">
    why is this text broken, it honestly sucks<br>why is this a thing<br>lorem ipsum
  </aba>

  <br>
  <center>
    &nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="text-decoration:dotted underline;" href="https://codepen.io/Shebadoge/full/bGBGrzN">&nbsp;OK&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><br>&nbsp;
  </center>
</div>
<br>
<div class="taskbar">
  <div style="text-shadow: 0.5px 0px #000000;" class="start">&nbsp;Start</div>

</div>
```

I've tried a while to fix this but it won't work.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/shebadoge

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `float:left` to the image-container you had. So the container width and height is getting in the way of the outer-class

So in order to fix this, you need to clear the float:

```
  .outer{
      clear:both; /*Added this style*/
  }
```

You can learn more about why do we need to clear floats here [CSS How and Why Clear Float](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pixelar Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pixelar Regular'), url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/38239/PIXELAR REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
}

a {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-style: outset;
  color: black;
  background-color: silver;
}

a:hover {
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #9a9999;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Pixelar Regular', sans-serif;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-style: inset;
  size: 1;
}

.outer {
  background-color: silver;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #c6c6c6;
  width: 380px;
  text-align: left;
  clear:both; /*Added this style*/
}

.un {
  background-color: #c30000;
  border-color: #d84040;
  padding: 00px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
}

html {
  background-color: #018281;
}

.taskbar {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  position: fixed;
  border-style: inset;
  height: 4%;
}

.start {
  background-color: silver;
  border-style: outset;
  width: 35px;
}

.start:hover {
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
  border-style: inset;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div style="float:left;transform:translateX(-50px)">
    <center>
      <img src="https://webstockreview.net/images/windows-95-icons-png-2.png" alt="My pc" width="150" style=”display:block”>
      <p style="transform:translateY(-47px)">My pc</p>
    </center>
  </div><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="outer">

    <div class="topbar" style="font-size:25px;color:white;text-shadow: 1px 0px #ffffff;text-align:left;">
      &nbsp;Windows
    </div>
    <aba style "text-align: left;">
      why is this text broken, it honestly sucks<br>why is this a thing<br>lorem ipsum
    </aba>

    <br>
    <center>
      &nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="text-decoration:dotted underline;" href="https://codepen.io/Shebadoge/full/bGBGrzN">&nbsp;OK&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><br>&nbsp;
    </center>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="taskbar">
    <div style="text-shadow: 0.5px 0px #000000;" class="start">&nbsp;Start</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```